# System.IO.FileNotFoundException in debug but not with exe

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, debugging, ioexception, image-load

I'll try to be simple and quick

I'm developing a program, a windows form actually.
I have a pictureBox and in the following line, when I run in debug mode(note that), I get an System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception:

```
pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromFile(".\\images\\no-avatar2.jpg");
```

The problem is that I don't get that exception when I run the exe file AND the file loads perfectly.
Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: *Always* use the full path to the file, you'll get in trouble when Environment.CurrentDirectory changes or somebody starts your program with the wrong working directory.  Create a full path from Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.

Comment: I didn't get that, sorry. "Always use the full path"? So, I can't use relative path anymore? I want this to work in whatever directory the user choose to install the program. I don't find this a very good idea. Can you explain more?

Comment: That's why you must use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, it tells you where the program was installed.

Comment: I see. But this is returns the full path WITH the filename and the extension of my exe. I want a quick solution, something like this:
pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromFile(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + "\\images\\no-avatar2.jpg");

Comment: Use the System.IO.Path.GetDirectory() method.  And use Path.Combine() to reliably create the new path string.  Your urge to find "quick solutions" don't help you find the proper solutions.

Comment: :) I think you misjudged me. I want the quickest AND the most correct solution combined. If what I asked cannot be done then I move to the next more complicated and more correct solution. But anyways, I use this:
pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromFile(System::IO::Path::GetDirectoryName(System::Reflection::Assembly::GetEntryAssembly()->Location) + "\\images\\no-avatar2.jpg");
and it works perfectly. I didn't use though the Path.Combine() you mention. I didn't understand it. What do you mean "reliably create"?
PS: Irrelevant, how can I vote your answer as correct if you answer as comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromFile(System::IO::Path::GetDirectoryName(System::Reflection::Assembly:‌:GetEntryAssembly()->Location) + "\\images\\no-avatar2.jpg");
```

and it works perfectly